# What's the difference between Software-Generated Interrupt and Software-Generated Exception?

Tags: exception, x86, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I am reading the Intel Manual 3A Chapter 6 Interrupt and Exception Handling.

Interrupt and Exception have 3 sources respectively.

For Software-Generated Interrupt, it says:

> **The INT n instruction** permits interrupts to be generated from within
>   software by supplying an interrupt vector number as an operand. For
>   example, the INT 35 instruction forces an implicit call to the
>   interrupt handler for interrupt 35. Any of the interrupt vectors from
>   0 to 255 can be used as a parameter in this instruction. If the
>   processor’s predefined NMI vector is used, however, the response of
>   the processor will not be the same as it would be from an NMI
>   interrupt generated in the normal manner. If vector number 2 (the NMI
>   vector) is used in this instruction, the NMI interrupt handler is
>   called, but the processor’s NMI-handling hardware is not activated.
>   Interrupts generated in software with the INT n instruction cannot be
>   masked by the IF flag in the EFLAGS register.

For Software-Generated Exceptions, it says:

> **The INTO, INT 3, and BOUND instructions** permit exceptions to be
>   generated in software. These instructions allow checks for exception
>   conditions to be performed at points in the instruction stream. For
>   example, INT 3 causes a breakpoint exception to be generated. The INT
>   n instruction can be used to emulate exceptions in software; but there
>   is a limitation. **If INT n provides a vector for one of the
>   architecturally-defined exceptions, the processor generates an
>   interrupt to the correct vector (to access the exception handler) but
>   does not push an error code on the stack.** This is true even if the
>   associated hardware-generated exception normally produces an error
>   code. The exception handler will still attempt to pop an error code
>   from the stack while handling the exception. Because no error code was
>   pushed, the handler will pop off and discard the EIP instead (in place
>   of the missing error code). This sends the return to the wrong
>   location.

So, what's the difference? Seems both leverage the `int n` instruction. How can I tell whether it generates an exception or an interrupt in a piece of assembly code?

Comment: It is an obscure detail that only matters to somebody that writes a protected-mode operating system.  As noted, he'd better then ensure that an INTn with n < 32 also generates an exception or the interrupt handler is going to misbehave.  Done by having the gate force a ring transition (aka DPL < CPL), I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the x86 architecture an exception is handled as an interrupt, nominally with an interrupt handler.
So interrupts and exceptions are terms that overlaps, the latter are a kind of the former.

Interrupt numbers from 0 to 31 are reserved for CPU exceptions, for example interrupt number 0 is the #DE (Divide error), interrupt number 13 is the #GP (General Protection).

When the CPU detects a condition that should rise an exception (like an access to a non present page) it performs a series of tasks.

First it pushes an error code if needed, some exceptions (like #PF and #GP) do, some (like #DE) don't.
The Section 6.15 of the [Intel manual 3](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) lists all the exceptions with their eventual error code.

Secondly it "calls" the appropriate interrupt handler which is like a far call but with *EFLAGS* pushed on the stack.

`int n` does only the second step, it calls an interrupt but doesn't push any error code as there is no error condition in the hardware in the first place (and because `int n` was there before the concept of *error codes*).
So it can be used to *emulate* exceptions, the software has to eventually push an appropriate error code.

When you see `int n` in the code, it is *never* an exception. It is an interrupt, that eventually is used to steer the control flow into a particular OS exception handler.

---

Trivia: `int3` (with no space) is special because it is encoded as `CC` which is only one byte (normal `int n` is `CD imm8`). This is useful for debugging, since the debugger can put it anywhere in the code segment.
`into` only generates the #OF exception if *OF = 1*.

Comment: Many thanks. So my understanding now is, Exception *may* have an error code. Interrupt *will not*.  Exception can be classified as `Fault`, `Trap`, `Abort`. And I checked the vector 0~31, all belong to one of these 3 types but the vector 3, which is NMI, an interrupt. Exceptions are from internal of the processor, while interrupt from external of the processor.

Comment: BTW, what does the `imm8` mean? And why being single-byte-coded makes `int 3`  can be put anywhere in the code segment?

Comment: @smwikipedia *imm8` means *8-bit immediate*, so for example `CD 21` is  `int 21h`, `CD 67` is `int 67h`. Sorry, didn't clarify that. Regarding `int 3`, I can answer by quoting Intel: "*This one byte form is valuable because it can be used to replace the first byte of any instruction with a
breakpoint, **including other one byte instructions**, without over-writing other code*". Which maybe is badly expressed in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Your really rock! :)

Comment: But if the first byte of an instruction is replaced, won't that instruction be invalid?

Comment: @smwikipedia Yes, but since x86 as variable length instructions the CPU decodes them progressively, as soon as a sequence of bytes is a valid instruction the CPU execute it (this is why no instruction can be a prefix of another). Since `int 3` is a byte long, the minimum instruction length, the CPU surely decode a stream of byte beginning with `CC` as `int 3`. This generates the #DB exception and the debugger restores the correct instruction in memory.

Comment: This details are very interesting. Could you tell me where I can find related reference? I guess I need to dig it myself... I mean your last comment about debugging.

Comment: @smwikipedia The [x86 tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has a lot of links. Unfortunately, I can't tell which ones are relevant to your question. Surely a copy of the Intel manuals is mandatory, along with some Google skills :)