# What does 'NMI-handling hardware is not activated' mean?

Tags: x86, interrupt

I am reading the Intel Manual 3A Chapter 6 Interrupt and Exception Handling.
I know int n can activate a interrupt,but i confuse about this sentence.

**Any of the interrupt vectors from 0 to 255 can be used as a parameter in this instruction. If the processor’s predefined NMI vector is used, however, the response of the processor will not be the same as it would be from an NMI interrupt generated in the normal manner. If vector number 2 (the NMI vector) is used in this instruction, the NMI interrupt handler is called, but the processor’s NMI-handling hardware is not activated.**

Why is there a different response between int 2 and an NMI interrupt generated in the normal manner?
What does the sentence 'processor’s NMI-handling hardware is not activated' mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Software-Generated Interrupt and Software-Generated Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501713/whats-the-difference-between-software-generated-interrupt-and-software-generate)

Comment: @Michael, that answer by Margaret is an excellent elaboration of this section, but it doesn’t talk about NMI specifically, so I don’t think it qualifies as a duplicate.

Comment: The processor prevents nested NMIs. That is, when an NMI occurs, further NMIs are blocked until an IRET. When “int 2” is executed, NMIs are not blocked. I’m not sure if that is the only difference.

Comment: There’s no error code for NMI. The exceptions with error code are 8, 10-14, and 17.